# Login form - hook_form_alter destinations broken

Tags: hooks, users, forms

I have a custom log in template along with some alterations. It seems to work just fine everywhere except where I have `...?destination=foo/bar`.

The template code is:

```
<div id="fdanconia_login">
  <div id="fdanconia_login_form">
    <?php print render(drupal_get_form('user_login', $form)); ?>
  </div>
  <div class="register_now">Don't have an account? <b>Register now</b></div>
  <div id="fdanconia_register_form">
    <?php print render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form')); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

The module code is:

```
function fdanconia_menu(){
  $items['login'] = array(
    'title' => 'Login',
    'page callback' => '_fdanconia_login',
    'access callback' => true,
  );
  return $items;
}

function fdanconia_theme(){
  $themes = array(
    'fdanconia_login' => array(
      'template' => 'fdanconia_login',
      'arguments' => array(),
    ),
  );
  return $themes;
}

function fdanconia_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  global $user;
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
      // Redirect users to the new login page
      if (isset($_GET['destination']) && $destination = $_GET['destination']) {
        $options = array('query' => array('destination' => $destination));
        unset($_GET['destination']);
      } else {
        $options = array();
      }
      if (arg(0) == 'user' && !$user->uid) drupal_goto('login', $options);
      $form['name']['#description'] = 'Email';
      $form['pass']['#description'] = 'Password';
    break;
    case 'user_register_form':
      if (arg(0) == 'user' && !$user->uid) drupal_goto('login', array('query' => array('destination' => $destination)));
      $form['account']['name']['#type'] = 'hidden';
      array_unshift($form['#validate'], '_fdanconia_login_validate');
    break;
  }
}

function _fdanconia_login() {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'fdanconia') . '/fdanconia.css');
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'fdanconia') . '/fda.js', 'file');
  return theme('fdanconia_login');
}

function _fdanconia_login_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $email = $form_state['values']['mail'];
  $form_state['input']['name'] = $email;
  $form_state['values']['name'] = $email;
  $form_state['complete form']['account']['name']['value'] = $email;
}
```

So, when I log in with a destination no matter what it redirects to the default log in page as if there were no destination parameter. However, the destination shows up in the URL. I can even manually put a destination in the URL and when I submit the form, I am not redirected to the proper destination. There is nothing in watchdog about the log in other than a session has been created.

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Hi, looking at the code I can't really see what it adds that isn't in the default login form (and there's a number of ways it's not doing things 'the proper FAPI way' I think). I just tried on a fairly fresh 7 install and the destination parameter redirected perfectly normally from the login screen. How is it that you want to customise the login process? If all you want to do is add css, js, and a custom theme function, then you can do it all with a much simpler form_alter function.

Comment: Because i want to add the login form to multiple places in the site, not as a block, but within content. I don't want to redirect users away from the content and break their flow. Also, there is some heavier work going on because I am also adding oauth stuff to the login and need to theme it as well. I took that part out of the template for simplicity of this question. Another reason, (trivial reason), is that we want /login to be the login and not /user...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal 7 redirection needs to both `$form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;` and `$form_state['redirect'] = 'whatever';`

```
//Implementation of hook_form_alter()
function custommade_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    switch($form_id) {
        case 'comment_node_article_form':
            $form['#submit'][] = 'custommade_custom_submit';
    }
}

//Custom submit handler
function _custommade_custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    $form_state['redirect'] = 'whatever';
}
```

Comment: Well, I cannot get this to work. Nothing I do changes the redirect path.

Answer (score 1):

I think in D7 you can also use the redirect property, this would be in your form_alter:

```
  $form_state['redirect'] = array('http://www.example.com/my-external-path', array('external' => TRUE));
```

$form_state['redirect'] takes the same values as drupal_goto(), which itself uses url() to generate its destination path. It is possible to add an array of options including 'external=TRUE' to your redirect value if redirect is external.

Not sure if this will help in your case though.

Comment: Well, I cannot get this to work. Nothing I do changes the redirect path.